# Non-USA zip code radius lookup

Tags: zipcode

I am coding a store locator page and part of the search is to be able to enter a zip code and a mile radius and do a search. I have been able to find a free source to download a csv of all USA based zip codes and their related longitude and latitude. However does anyone know where to find a CSV of Non USA based postal codes and their related longitude and latitude?

I am looking for a free download/website where I can download a csv of all non USA zipcodes and their related lon and lat. not a saas company to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should google around before you ask.

http://www.geopostcodes.com

Comment: actually this doesn't provide free zips, just a list of their formats for free